# How to export custom entity using Features?

Tags: entities, features

I am trying to export custom entity using Features module but I am not able to see anything under create features.

I have enabled exportable as TRUE in `hook_entity_info`.

I have already added `entity_exportable_schema_fields()` under my custom schema .

Comment: You can create custom entities using ECK. Maybe that gives you something. If not at least you can see how it's done there.

Comment: You have created this entity in a particular module.
Right?
then give the dependency for it.
So, after enable it, your custom entity will create.
:)

Answer (score 1):

Follow https://www.drupal.org/node/1021526 for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go to "Create Feature" and search under the list "Entity Types" for your entity, that will work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to used the [ECK module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) to generated your custom entities. This would allows you to export them easily with the Features module.