# How to export entity instances created with ECK?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, entities

I have created my custom entity types (and bundles) using [ECK module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck).
Is it possible to export entities from website, for example using Features?

I have found [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85787/how-to-export-custom-entity-using-features) but as I understand, it is concerning
exporting of entity type configuration. But I would need to export entity instances. Is it possible to use Features or any other Drupal module to achieve it?

Comment: What entity instances you are trying to export?

Comment: I am creating instances with method entity_create http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_create/7